# Two computers, one joins channel successfully, one does not

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have two computers connecting to a phoenix server. The js being served to both is identical. Both are running the same version of Chrome. One is windows, the other is OSX.

The OSX computer behaves properly. The windows computer however never get's an "ok" back on the chan.join() call.

```
let socket = new Socket('ws://testapi.com:4000/socket', opts);
socket.connect();
let chan = socket.channel('rooms:' + room);
chan.join()
  .receive("ok", ({messages}) => console.log("catching up", messages) )
  .receive("error", ({reason}) => console.log("failed join", reason) )
  .receive("timeout", () => console.log("Networking issue. Still waiting..."));
```

After a few seconds the windows computer will log out the timeout message.
In the network activity, I see that the websocket connection is being made, and the only traffic on it is:

```
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":"1"}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":"2"}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":"3"}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":null}
{"topic":"rooms:test","event":"phx_join","payload":{}, "ref":"4"}
```

etc.

I haven't been able to get any hints of anything out of the server logs. No errors being thrown.

Comment: Is this server running on the OSX machine? Are you 100% sure that you have network access from the windows machine to the server?

Comment: The server is a digital ocean droplet. The windows machine does interact with the server via POST to authenticate before the socket connection. Also it looks like `socket.connect()` works just fine. it's `chan.join()` that's having the problem.

Comment: Tried adding logging to the channel on the server to make sure its taking the code path you think it is?

Comment: I logged out as much as I could on the server. It looks like the channel connect is firing and returning {:ok, socket} properly, but it's never making it to the join callback.